# Constructors and Destructors in Lua?

Tags: constructor, lua, programming-languages, destructor

I am new to Lua and learning some of the concept by comparing them with other programming languages like Python and Java. I know Java and python both have constructors and destructors. But I didn't find one that is written in pure Lua. I have seen some examples that uses C/C++ with Lua for the constructors but is there any way to make constructors and destructors just in Lua language?

Comment: Define `YourClass:new()` function and use it as a constructor.  Use `__gc` metamethod if you need something non-trivial inside a destructor.

Comment: Just to be more clarified, could you please give an example by implementing both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor is any function that creates an object and returns it. To define a destructor, you need a metatable with a [`__gc` metamethod](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5.3). The `__gc` metamethod will be called either when the object is garbage-collected or at the end of the program.

```
local mt = {
  -- Destructor
  __gc = function(self)
    print('Garbage-collecting ' .. self.name)
  end,
}

-- Constructor
local function newObject(name)
  local o = {name = name}
  setmetatable(o, mt)
  return o
end
```

Comment: Since the `__gc` metamethod is called non-deterministically (by garbage collector), a more correct term for it is “finalizer”. Destructors were introduced in Lua 5.4 in the form of [to-be-closed variables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.8) and the `__close` metamethod

Comment: Does it mean that there was no implementation of destructors before Lua 5.4 and only the garbage collector did the job?

Comment: @anu111: If you want the destructor to be called as soon as the variable goes out of scope, then yes, to-be-closed variables were introduced in Lua 5.4. For pre-5.4, `__gc` could do the same job, so it's still more than what plain, automatic garbage collection does, but you can't control when `__gc` gets called.